# What is a רופא אומן?

Tags: rambam, medicine

The Rambam in the second Perek of Chovel U'Mazik writes the following:

הלכה יח
אמר לו המזיק אני ארפא אותך או יש לי רופא שמרפא בחנם אין שומעין לו אלא מביא רופא אומן ומרפאהו בשכר.

What is a רופא אומן and how is he different than a רופא?

Comment: I vaguely recall a discussion of a "proven" healer who has a track record of success. No sources right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_One_Who_Injures_a_Person_or_Property.2.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) translates *rofe uman* as **competent**. [R Eliyahu Touger](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088909/jewish/Chovel-uMazzik-Chapter-Two.htm) as **professional**.

Going back to the source in the gemara [Bava Kamma 85a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.85a.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), one sees a more nuanced story (based on artscroll commentary there)

- Even if the assailant is a qualified physician the victim can refuse treatment because a patient must be comfortable with his doctor
- Even if the doctor is qualified but is a relative to the assailant (treating the patient as a favor to his relative), the victim can refuse his services because he will not devote his entire heart and mind to the needs of the patient
- A faraway doctor (presumably at lower fee) is disqualified because he will return home afterwards and won't care for his reputation

Answer (score -1):

**Uman** everywhere means one thing - **one who charges for his work**. As the Gemmorah in Kiddushin 30 or 82 about the one's duty of teaching his sons Umanut - meaning to make earning from a profession.

THe big Nafka Mina is in his responsibilities as a Shomer - if he heals for free he's a Shomer Hinam, but if he charges money he's a Shomer Sochor with bigger a responsibility.

THerefore, the Mazik should **hire a doctor that charges for his work** so his responsibility would be maximized.

Comment: but see the gemara I refer to above - charging is not enough in this specific case, e.g., a faraway doctor who charges is disqualified